# Can we use same MongoDB connection to select different DBs?

Tags: php, mongodb, web-development-server, database

I'm using more than 1 DBs in my project. I have a doubt that whether I can select all those DBs with same connection variable or should I use a separate connection for each DB?

Example:

```
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
$dbm = $conn->DB1;

$dbm2 = $conn->DB2;
```

or

```
$conn2 = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
$dbm2 = $conn2->DB2;
```

Which one is the right approach?

Comment: If you find an answer to this, can you post it ?